# Changing Default Welcome Screen of GraphiQL

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, documentation, graphiql

I am working on documenting my graphQL endpoints so that they show on the GraphiQL IDE. I am using the springboot spring-boot-starter-graphql, version 3.1.1 package which includes graphiQL. So far I have been using comments in my graphql schema files so that they generate in the docs section.

The part I am stuck on is that there is a welcome screen that I want to change that appears when you first load up graphiQL in the sandbox interactice area. This appears to be associated with the prop defaultQuery, however I cannot pass anything into this prop.

[Image of Welcome Message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RwTh.png)

Additionally there seems to be top level text that I cant access in the docs section either.

[Docs Section Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9V9w.png)

I want to have as much control over what text is presented for my documentation. How can I change this default behavior?

I have tried to access props listed in the graphiQL resources through my application properties file however this doesnt seem to work. I think there is a way forward using a completely custom webpage, but I think this is drastic for what I am trying to do in my use case.